# The current version of deployment in script seems to have alot of issues in deploying my

Tags: erc-20, hardhat-deploy

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const initAmount = hre.ethers.parseEther("0.01");
  const sleekToken = await hre.ethers.deployContract("SleekToken", [100000000, 50], {
    value: initAmount
  });

  await sleekToken.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    `Initial of ${ethers.formatEther(
      initAmount
    )}ETH deployed to ${sleekToken.target}`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**This is the error I get**

```
ProviderError: err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0xAb16A1936381dd63cc0B28B85Ab9277d1d8c6BdE have 210612114657000 want 10000000000000000 (supplied gas 30000000)
```

Comment: The error is quite simple, your wallet doesn't have funds for the gas. Consider adding native tokens before sending any transactions

Comment: I have 2.5 eth on my sepolia testnet wallet
How do I add native tokens before sending any transaction....Any hint on that please?

Comment: 2.5 is enough to deploy a contract, can you confirm if you are deploying on sepolia? just check once your config, run command, etc.

Comment: I re-entered the correct link to deploying on sepolia and it gives me an error saying "execution reverted".

Comment: @KriekDev It could be that there's a problem with the constructor, likely wrong input parameters.

Comment: @Ismael Do you have any recent repo I can use as case study?